# add a string to the beginning of every file in java

Tags: java, bufferedreader, stringbuilder, bufferedwriter

I would like to read from a text file, add a string(A,) to the beginning of every line of this file, and write it back to the same file.

Is there an easier way than reading from a file, building a string buffer, and then parsing each of those lines to add the string that I need before adding to the file.

File

```
hello,1
hello,2
hello,3
hello,4
hello,5
```

Looking for

```
A,hello,1
A,hello,2
A,hello,3
A,hello,4
A,hello,5
```

Comment: You can read from one file and write to another with additional characters at start of each line. When you are done remove original file and rename new one to replace original.

Comment: this has been answered so many times before, search SO please.

Comment: If you're just worried about the outcome you can use a program like Sublime Text with it's multi-line editing feature.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way I can think of:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("file"));
String[] list = lines.toArray(new String[0]);
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("file");
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    list[i] = "A," + list[i];
    writer.write(list[i]);
}
writer.flush();
```